# Is it normal that conversationId keeps increasing after each page request?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, seam, seam-conversation

Hi I'm building a Seam application and have a question:

I got a stateless session bean (default seam scope) with a delete and a select method.
A page which contains a datamodel loads and got links to select and delete each row (both links refer to the actionmethods in the bean).

The delete method deletes the selected row from the list and returns null (reloads page).
The select method loads a new page where the selected row can be edited.

Each time a link in the datamodel is clicked and an action gets fired, the conversationId gets increased. Is this normal behaviour since im not even in a conversation? If it ain't normal behaviour, what's best practice to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is normal behavior in Seam.
Seam uses the conversation in built-in components, filters and servlets to garbage-collect among other things.

So even if you don't explicitly use a conversation, seam will always create a temporary one.

Comment: OK, thanks for making that clear =) So basically if your server is running for a while, the user can get a conversationId > 10000?